# C# Connecting to TFS and Checking Work Item Status

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm trying to connect to TFS and check the status of a work item.  However, every time I execute the code, I get the following error message:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader.dll*

*Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)*

Occurs when code hits:  **WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));**

I have the following DLL referenced:
    - Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
    - Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client
    - Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader

Here is my code.

```
    private static void connectToTfs(int executionType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting to work on TFS");

        // Supply the credentials of the user who will be impersonated to create the bug 
        ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs =
            new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://URL:8080/Team"), credentials);

        if (tfs.HasAuthenticated == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to TFS");
            WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));

            switch (executionType)
            {
                case 1:
                    //create query
                    string queryString = "Select [State] From WorkItems Where [ID] = '4123567' ";

                    //Dictionary for storing variables
                    Dictionary<string, string> variables = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    variables.Add("ID", "State");

                    Query query = new Query(workItemStore, queryString, variables);
                    WorkItemCollection results = query.RunQuery();

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in variables)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ID {0} state is {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                    }

                    break;
             }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1695433) possibly has a workaround.

It suggested to manually locate the GAC32 version of `Microsoft.WITDataStore` rename it to `Microsoft.WITDataStore32` and add to the bin folder of your project